# Elasticsearch list all rivers

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I list all the rivers in Elasticsearch, I'm new to it and was adding rivers on the fly and I want to do some cleaning.
The [official documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/index.html) doesn't mention a way to do so..

Comment: Guess, but try this -  `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_river/_meta`

Comment: No handler found for uri [/_river/_meta] and method [GET]

Comment: I didn't ever come across this functionality when I was using rivers, really you should be keeping note of this. Good for future reference. Sorry I couldn't be of any help.

Comment: Just a quick note that rivers are being deprecated in Elasticsearch 1.5. https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this will do the trick for you, as `_river` is an index like any other it can be queried like one. -

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_river/_search?q=*
```

Comment: Shouldn't be an XGET ?

Comment: @Sekai yes sorry, made the changes. `GET` as not posting a body and was never a `PUT` however `PUT also does work. It's early. Hope that solved your problem?

Comment: I will believe that I have only 1 river, because this returned only 1 river! isn't there any "multi" criteria ? or should I run this again after deleting my river ..

Comment: Add another river and see if it returns two, this is query should return all due to the wildcard.

Comment: Or delete the river, depends if you're on a dev environment or not.

Comment: No problem Sekai - I recommend downloading and installing this - https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head .. Very useful for administering your cluster, viewing all your indices and also querying your data. Have a nice day.

Comment: No query would be way better than q=* , it would map to a match_all query instead of a query_string. An alternative is to use the get mappings, so that you wouldn't even execute a query. `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_river/_mapping`.

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback on Nate's answer, if you throw the following line into a browser, you will get output that's actually readable (notice the "pretty" parameter was added):

```
http://localhost:9200/_river/_search?q=*&pretty
```